It does not fetch data when the page is loaded, only when npm run build is done
Friends, because it only brings the data when npm run build is executed and not when you add a new data, that is, it does not fetch every time the page is loaded, on my localhost it works normally, I am using xata, it is like prisma, please, I have had this problem for days
I understand that to do GET it is no longer necessary to use /api/blogs/route.ts  ,only to do Post delete and put

I hope to know why it does not bring the data every time the page is loaded and only brings the data when npm run build is executed
